# Websockets messages not being sent

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, windows-media-player

This is a Windows Media Player C# code I'm working on, that sends a TCP WebSocket message back to the client saying that the mp3 audio is still playing.

I'm using `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.StatusChange`, and the `StatusChange` triggers the message accordingly it seems, but even though I can receive messages from the client in my WMP C# application.

I can't figure out why it won't send the `var message_back = "Audio still Playing...";` back to the client.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "";
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"C:\Audio\song1.MP3";
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();

    this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.StatusChange += new EventHandler(axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange);

    this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.StatusChange += new EventHandler(serverStartup);
}

public void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.status == "Finished")
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "CONTINUE PLAYING...";
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
    }
}

public void serverStartup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
    var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
    var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8181");

    server.Start(socket =>
    {
        socket.OnOpen = () =>
        {
            allSockets.Add(socket);
        };

        socket.OnClose = () =>
        {                     
            allSockets.Remove(socket);
        };

        socket.OnMessage = message =>
        {
            allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("Echo: " + message));    
        };
    });

    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.status == "Finished")
    {
        var message_back = "Audio still Playing...";
        foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
        {
            socket.Send(message_back);
        }

        // I tried using this line bellow, but it won't work either.
        //allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("Echo: " + message_back));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand: your code says if(Finished)...send("still playing") ???

Comment: When the axWindowsMediaPlayer1.status detects the "Finished" state, I need to send a message to the Websocket, in this example that message is simply "Audio still Playing...", but in the final code will be something else, like this audio is done playing..., etc.

Comment: Ok - however, your if(Finished) is in your serverStartup(), should it be in the axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange() method ?

Comment: The axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange() method doesn't have to be inside that serverStartup() function, but that's where I need a little hand, I can't figure out how to send the message without having that inside that function serverStartup()

Comment: I don't understand why this is tagged 'php' :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing quite a bit here, however, assuming your `axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange` is being called - add your message sender in there:

```
// made this global for simplicity...
static List<IWebSocketConnection> allSockets;
allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();

public void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.status == "Finished")
    {
        // send message...
        var message_back = "Starting again...";
        foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
        {
            socket.Send(message_back);
        }

        // I assume this restarts playback...
        lblMessage.Text = "CONTINUE PLAYING...";
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
    }

}
```

Comment: I just tried that but first, the variable allSockets is throwing an exception

"The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

so then I moved the variable inside the function but even though there is no errors, it won't send the message "Starting again..." :(

Comment: My mistake, `var` is for local variables, see edit above

Comment: Now the static variable says: Error 4 'Application.Form1.allSockets' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: I changed the code to: 
static List<IWebSocketConnection> allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>(); 
and now all works!!! THANK YOU!